# Riki Ult physical or magic?

Tags: dota-2

Is riki Ult magic or physical?

I could not find the answer in hero's reference.

My guess is depending  on  riki items it can be both.  But this
Is just a  guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riki's Tricks of the Trade simply performs Riki's regular attack on every target in the area of effect. Normally this is physical damage, but depending on items that may proc on hit, such as Skull Basher and Monkey King Bar, it may additionally deal magical or pure damage.